# add filter not working when cancatenating variables

Tags: theme-development

I am getting a problem while applying a code. My code works fine when i use only one variable. e.g;

```
    $posts_per_page = 'posts_per_page=3';
```

but it doesn't work if i use concatenation.e.g

```
    $posts = "posts_per_page=";
    $number = 3;
    $posts_per_page = $posts. $number;
```

my full code looks like .

```
    function blogs() {?>
    <article>

        <?php // Display blog posts on any page @ https://m0n.co/l
        $temp = $wp_query; 
        $wp_query= null;
        $wp_query = new WP_Query();
$posts = 'post_per_page=';
$number = 3;
$posts_per_page =  $posts . $number ; 
        $wp_query->query( apply_filters('change_number_of_posts_home', $posts_per_page) . '&paged='.$paged);
        while ($wp_query->have_posts()) : $wp_query->the_post(); ?>

        <h2><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="Read more"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h2>
        <?php openblogger_posted_on();
                openblogger_posted_by(); ?>

        <?php endwhile; ?>

        <?php wp_reset_postdata(); ?>

    </article>
<?php
}
```

Can anyone tell me why the doesn't work. Also, i am trying to use filter for $number = 3; so that user can change the number easily.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look at your filter:

```
apply_filters('change_number_of_posts_home', $posts_per_page)
```

The value being passed to it is `$posts_per_page`, so of course they can't change `$number`.

If you want only the number to be filtered then that's the part that should have the filter applied:

```
$number = apply_filters('change_number_of_posts_home', 3 );
```

Then the query can just look like this:

```
$wp_query->query( 'post_per_page=' . $number . '&paged='.$paged);
```

They're not relevant to the question, but some other things I noticed about your code:

- You shouldn't be overwriting `$wp_query` like that. Just use a new variable for your custom query.
- You can pass the arguments to `new WP_Query( $args )` rather than needing to run `->query()` as a separate step.
- The code would be easier to read if you pass the arguments as an array, rather than a query string.
- Each individual post should be an `<article>`. You're wrapping all the posts in a single article tag.

Comment: can you please send me a code in which i can write an individual article rather than wrapping

Comment: ? Just move the tags so they're inside the loop.

Comment: can't understand what you are saying. Can you please edit my code. so that i get the post or just post another answer.

Comment: now i got you you were talking of article tags